# Cleaning table tennis rubbers

Tags: equipment, table-tennis, racket, maintenance

I just bought a new table tennis paddle and I've bought a new cleaner, but I forgot to purchase one of those sponges.

Is there any problem with using a plain microfiber cloth to clean my table tennis paddle to remove dust?

What are some acceptable clothes or sponges I could use to clean a table tennis paddle?

Answer (score 2):

I find anything that doesn't leave fibres on the rubber works. I often just use a paper towel.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't damage the surface or leave fibres or dirt on the rubber, any soft material should be okay. In general you don't even need a special cleaner. Water is enough to get rid of dust. From time to time an additional drop of dishwashing liquid helps to keep fat/grease away from your racket surfaces. But the cleaner can be stored easier in your sports bag. :-)