# What cleaning agent is safe to use for ping pong paddles?

Tags: equipment, table-tennis, racket, maintenance

I just got a new ping pong paddle, and I want to be able to clean the rubbers without damaging them or affecting their tackiness.  On Amazon I see lots of expensive little spray bottles for cleaning paddles.  What substances are in those bottles?  Perhaps I can clean the paddle using stuff I have at home.  Would rubbing alcohol, or soapy water, or something else be safe to use to clean the rubbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleaning table tennis rubbers](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5533/cleaning-table-tennis-rubbers)

Comment: No it does not. That question is about what cloth to use to wipe off the cleaning agent.

Answer (score 0):

When I was most active (decades ago), I used Butterfly's Tackiness Drive on my forehand and Sriver on my backhand.  What I used to clean both rubber sheets was simple window spray cleaner and paper towels.  In a pinch you can get by with just water, but Windex (or any other variant) does quite nicely.  I saw no adverse results from using it over a period of many years.